# HAproxy + Transparent Squid configuration

Tags: proxy, squid, haproxy

I tried configuring squid to be a transparent proxy and then connecting it to a HAProxy load balancing server on CentOS 7.

My squid configuration is this:

```
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow ldap
http_access allow localhost

# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
http_access deny all

# Squid normally listens to port 3128
http_port 3128 intercept
visible_hostname squid.proxy

http_port 5532 ssl-bump cert=/etc/squid/ssl_cert/myCA.pem generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=4MB
sslcrtd_program /usr/lib64/squid/security_file_certgen -s /var/lib/ssl_db -M 4MB
acl step1 at_step SslBump1

ssl_bump peek step1
ssl_bump bump all
```

I ran the following commands for my firewall rules:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-forward-port=port=80:proto=tcp:toport=3128:toaddr=x.x.x.x
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=3128/tcp
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=80/tcp
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-masquerade
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

Then on my sysctl.conf

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

Restarted my Squid service.

On my HAProxy server I added the following configuration:

```
frontend transparent
        bind *:80 transparent
        mode tcp
        use_backend bk_squid

backend bk_squid
        mode tcp
        option http-server-close
        option forwardfor
        balance leastconn
        source 0.0.0.0 usesrc clientip
        cookie SERVERID insert nocache indirect
        server transparent1 10.88.42.29:80 check fall 3 rise 2
        server transparent2 10.88.42.30:80 check fall 3 rise 2
```

Honestly, I just combined all the configuration items I found from various online forums and well, it did not work. I need help on which parts of the configuration should I keep/add/remove. It works if I use the IP of the Server but if I use the HAProxy IP it does not. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Note: The port 5532 on my squid proxy still works normally. Meanwhile port 3128 does not (Code 409 as I haven't configured my client yet).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Transparent squid proxy LB on HAProxy

Comment: You should try this step by step. First with only squid or only haproxy, then the other then both together. Here you have something, you tell "it doesn't work" and expect a magical solution to be given. I'd have asked the same as Jiri B, but you'll just repeat again what's already provided by the title. Check: https://xyproblem.info/ too.

Comment: Actually I'm still waiting for the testing of the transparent proxy to be done. I'm just "setting it up" for the next step which is load balancing in HAProxy in advance. And I'm wondering why it's not working since I want it to go **User > HAProxy:80 > Squid:80**. And get the same log output as when I do **User > Squid:80**. Hope this helps.

Comment: By **>** I mean "connects to"